# Magento2: Class not found error

Tags: magento2, category, catalogsearch, category-products

Product category page is not working.

My Magento v2.0 Got the error below.

```
use Magento\Framework\EntityManager\MetadataPool
```

How can I solve the issue. ?

Comment: what exactly is the error?

Comment: Can you provide more details about this error. Where have you call it? Pin the screenshot of the exception.

Comment: Hi, @KirillKorushkin When i run the reindex command then got the error class not found Magento\Framework\EntityManager\MetadataPool

Comment: Hi, @HelgeB When i run the reindex command then got the error class not found Magento\Framework\EntityManager\MetadataPool

Comment: After i check  the under Magento\Framework\EntityManager\MetadataPool file not found because my Magento v2.17

Comment: So how can i replace the file or code in Magento v2.17. @HelgeB

Comment: If you are missing a file which is used by Magentos own code in your filesystem you most likely have a problem with your Magento installation. Try to reinstall Magento and you will find the file at the right place

Comment: Have you looked in the system.log file, which is under /var/log folder? Does there is any record around this error?

Comment: I have installed Layered filter navigation so got the error. @HelgeB

Comment: Not error got in file @KirillKorushkin

Comment: Check all docBlocks in your code, where you has mantioned \MetadataPool as returm object ( the proper way should be: @return \Magento\Framework\EntityManager\MetadataPool).

Comment: Plugin class Test\Shopby\Plugin\Catalog\Model\Indexer\Product\Eav\Action\Full doesn't exist @KirillKorushkin

Comment: When i run the reindex command same error for \Magento\Framework\EntityManager\MetadataPool

Comment: I have check MetadataPool is not found

Comment: Do you mean this class file in not exists by that path in your Magento installation: /vendor/magento/framework/EntityManager/MatadaPool.php?

Comment: Yes, Not in my Magento becuse Magento version is 2.0.17 @KirillKorushkin

Comment: /vendor/magento/framework/EntityManager/MatadaPool.php this file available for Magento 2.1 and 2.2 @KirillKorushkin

Comment: How can i replace code for Magneto 2.0.17?